# Create geometry in ArcPad

Tags: geometry, arcpad, vbscript

I want to create a point geometry in ArcPad 10 VBScript, to make custom feature drawing. So I want to create point geometry, then

```
 record.shape = point
```

or

```
records.AddNew(point)
```

I want to create point, line and polygon geometries.

I searched a lot but I haven't found how to create geometry.

I don't know if there's another simple manner to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how to create geometry object

```
set point = Application.CreateAppObject("Point")
```